# Set Google Maps (Default/Terrain/Satellite) type when opening Turn By Turn Navigation using Android Intent plus package: Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps, android-intent, maps

Is there a way to set the type of map in **google maps URL** to open a map with desired map type (like satellite, default or terrain) when using the https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent_plus package?
Currently, my code is-

```
              if (Platform.isAndroid) {
                                  AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
                                    action: 'action_view',
                                    data:
                                        'https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=${appState.position.latitude},${appState.position.longitude}&destination=${riderLocation.latitude},${riderLocation.longitude}&travelmode=driving&dir_action=navigate',
                                  );
                                  await intent.launch();
                                }
```

**The map opens in the mode which is set in the google maps app, but I want to specify the map type myself as terrain or default and not as satellite.**
Is there any way to specify this in URL? If not, is their any other way I can achieve the same functionality?

Comment: I am a non-flutter developer,but an Android developer using Java, but still, I did a great deal of research to find if we can achieve opening satellite view using intents. But what I found is there is no way using intents. You have to integrate maps sdk in your app to show a interactive map in your activity, and from there only you can set default map typw when maps instance is initialised.